# Hovering a specific number of buttons in a button group based on int variable?

Tags: javascript

i'm new to Javascript and is trying to create the following functionality:
I have a group of buttons. The number of buttons that are hovered should depend on a numeric value I provide.

So say I provide the value 4, four boxes out of five should be hovered.

I've found a piece of javascript code that i'm attempting to customise into this. However in this code, the added class "active" only happens on click.

How can I change the code, so the class is added irrespectively of the click?

My Javascript

```
<script>
var leitnerbox = 4;
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < leitnerbox; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>
```

My CSS

```
<style>
/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

My HTML

```
<body>

<h1> Buttons </>

<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```

My result

```js
var leitnerbox = 4;
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < leitnerbox; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        this.className += " active";
    });
}
```

```css
    /* Style the buttons */
    .btn {
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      padding: 10px 16px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    /* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
    .active, .btn:hover {
      background-color: #666;
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
<h1> Buttons </>
<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```

Thanks for reading this

Comment: So for example if you have five button - no matter you only want the `four` to have the class `active` when you click on each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove eventListener.

```
const leitnerbox = 4;
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
for (let i = 0; i < leitnerbox; i++) {
  btns[i].classList.add("active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add an input where you can write the number.

**HTML**:

```
<input type=“number” id=“quantity” />
<h1> Buttons <h1/>

<div id="myDIV">
     <button class="btn">1</button>

      <button class="btn">2</button>
      <button class="btn">3</button>
      <button class="btn">4</button>
      <button class="btn">5</button>
 </div>
```

Then you can add the change eventListener to the input e call a function like this that adds the "active" class to the buttons.
**JS**:

```
(function() {
    function myFunction(){
        var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
        var btnToActivate = header.querySelectorAll('.btn:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+' + this.value + ')');
        console.log("btnToActivate " + btnToActivate);

        for (const button of btnToActivate) {
              button.classList.add("active");
        }
    }   

    document.getElementById("quantity").addEventListener("change", myFunction);
})();
```

**JSFiddle**:
https://jsfiddle.net/9feu8rqc/

**EDIT**:
Additionally you can remove the class "active" of the buttons whne you reduce the value whit this js.

```
function() {
    function myFunction(){
        var quantity = parseInt(this.value);
        if (quantity >= 0){
            var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
            var activeButtons =  header.querySelectorAll('.btn.active');
            
            //Activate Buttons
            var btnToActivate = header.querySelectorAll('.btn:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+' + quantity + ')');

            for (const button of btnToActivate) {
                button.classList.add("active");
            }

            //Deactivate buttons
            var numerOfButtons = header.querySelectorAll('.btn').length;
            var btnToDectivate = header.querySelectorAll('.btn:nth-child(n+' + (quantity + 1) + '):nth-child(-n+' + activeButtons.length + ')');

            for (const button of btnToDectivate) {
                button.classList.remove("active");
            }
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("quantity").addEventListener("change", myFunction);
})();
```

**JSFIDDLE**:
https://jsfiddle.net/9feu8rqc/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you've other buttons on the page and want only the buttons in the #myDIV to be effected, try this.

```
const leitnerbox = 4;
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('#myDIV .btn');

for(let i = 0; i < leitnerbox; i++) {
  btns[i].classList.add('active');
}
```